# SSRS/Report Builder: Details field not justifying equally

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

[image]
I have a project in Report Builder. I'm trying to center-justify a field (a text field). Everything looked great. I changed the size of the field's width a bit. The next time I looked, the column was justifying some words differently than others.

- FIELD 1
- __Inside
- __Inside
- _Outside-trial
- __Inside
- _Outside-trial
- __Inside

So, the word (result) "inside" is showing up slightly to the right. And "outside" is showing up differently. The longer word ("Outside-trial") is showing up more left-justified than the shorter word ("Inside"). The "_" represents a space. All of the words are supposed to be center justified.

Also, changing the justification to left, center, or right, does not reset the issue. I also deleted the entire field and re-inserted it back into the report, but had the same issue. In Properties, all of the justification and padding are as they should be.

I opened a whole new report project, and added the field and still had the problem. My data source is SQL Server. None of the other fields are having any issue. I'm stumped.

Comment: Take the spaces off, then use centre align?  Also, post screenshots of the textbox properties window and the properties view

Comment: can you add ltrim(rtrim(field1)) to your query?

Comment: Also, as a suggestion to clean up report. This column seems boolean. Converting the column to Inside Trial (?) and displaying check boxes might be more visually appealing.

Comment: @JohnHC I don't actually have any spaces. I was just using the "_" underscore in my post to demonstrate the misalignment of the two different words in FIELD 1. _ = 1 space, __ = 2 spaces.

Comment: @KeithL --that did it. Thank you! I wonder why it was creating white space like that.

Comment: @DPool34 - If's it's truly a concern then I would look at the underlying source. you can also create a field like "*" + field1 + "*" to see the spacing and view in courier so that all characters are same width